# How we can integrate truffle with Jenkins?

Tags: solidity, truffle

is it possible to add truffle on Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, previously I wrote an answer for getting truffle working for various CI services and this gist also supports the same idea https://gist.github.com/maikotrindade/2d544de08215085abfbba59ce3378a2c.

[What Continuous Integration services support running Truffle Solidity tests?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47188/what-continuous-integration-services-support-running-truffle-solidity-tests/59176#59176)

As for Jenkins, I assume you can use a docker image or install ganache and quietly run it while running truffle tests.