# How to run Truffle Solidity tests in Gitlab CI?

Tags: truffle, ganache-cli

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file, inspired by [@GrandFleet's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47188/what-continuous-integration-services-support-running-truffle-solidity-tests/59176):

```
image: node:latest
  
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

stages:
  - test

test_async:
  stage: test
  services:
   - trufflesuite/ganache-cli
  script:
   - npm install truffle
   - ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js compile
   - ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js migrate --network gitlab
   - ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js test --network gitlab
```

When I run this on Gitlab, I get this error on `./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js migrate --network gitlab`:

```
$ ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js migrate --network gitlab
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
Unknown network "gitlab". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks.
Truffle v5.4.25 (core: 5.4.25)
Node v17.2.0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Should I set up a Gitlab network in my truffle-config.js? And if so, how?

EDIT:

Here is my truffle-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.10",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
       optimizer: {
         enabled: false,
         runs: 200
       },
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, you could try adding a gitlab network, or using the development network instead.

Comment: @Ismael And how exactly do I do that? That was my real question

Comment: What does your `truffle-config.js` look like?

Comment: I edited my question with the truffle-config.js file

Comment: Can you try using `--network development` instead?

Comment: Of course, I didn't set up a network for testing! So I did define a 'ropsten' network in truffle-config and did --network ropsten, and it's all good!

Comment: It will be nice if you can answer with the solution for your case, so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run tests on Gitlab CI, we need to use a test network such like Ropsten, Kovan or Rinkeby. In the truffle-config.js, in networks, add (if using Ropsten, in this case):

```
ropsten: {
      provider: () => {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, rpc_url);
      },
      network_id: '3',
    }
```

and the .gitlab-ci.yml file should look like:

```
image: node:latest
  
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

stages:
  - test

test_async:
  stage: test
  services:
   - trufflesuite/ganache-cli
  script:
   - echo "MNEMONIC"=$MNEMONIC >> ".env"
   - export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
   - npm install truffle
   - ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js compile
   - ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js migrate --network ropsten
   - ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js test --network ropsten
```

Where --network ropsten refers to the "ropsten" network defined in truffle-config.js.

I have written a more detailed solution in this tutorial: https://blog.benjaminazoulay.com/how-to-run-truffle-tests-in-gitlab-ci